# Ray Tracer Refraction on glass surfaces not working

Tags: rust, raytracing

I'm working through Ray Tracing in One Weekend (The rust version) here:
https://misterdanb.github.io/raytracinginrust/

But after adding Dielectrics (Glass), something is way off with my refraction on glass spheres.  I've done troubleshooting, but the math looks correct in reference to both the Rust version and the C++ version this was based on.  The expected image is this:
[image: Expected]

But my code is generating this:

[image]

My github link is: https://github.com/jsjutzi/rust-ray-tracer

The only code I've added for refraction and glass materials respectively is:

```
pub fn refract(self, n: Vec3, etai_over_etat: f64) -> Vec3 {
   let cos_theta = (-1.0 * self).dot(n).min(1.0);
   let r_out_perp = etai_over_etat * (self + cos_theta * n);
   let r_out_parallel = -(1.0 - r_out_perp.length().powi(2)).abs().sqrt() * n;
   r_out_perp + r_out_parallel
}
```

And:

```
pub struct Dielectric {
 ir: f64,
}

impl Dielectric {
  pub fn new(index_of_refraction: f64) -> Dielectric {
    Dielectric {
        ir: index_of_refraction,
    }
}


impl Scatter for Dielectric {
  fn scatter(&self, r_in: &Ray, rec: &HitRecord) -> Option<(Color, Ray)> {
     let refraction_ratio = if rec.front_face {
         1.0 / self.ir
     } else {
        self.ir
     };

     let unit_direction = r_in.direction();
     let refracted = unit_direction.refract(rec.normal, refraction_ratio);
     let scattered = Ray::new(rec.p, refracted);

     Some((Color::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), scattered))
}
```

I'm not even sure if the issue is refraction itself, or if I screwed something else up earlier in my build and it's just now surfacing because of refraction/glass surfaces being added.  I've backtracked several chapters and haven't found anything obvious that I missed earlier on, and I also read up on Snell's Law a bit and don't seen an obvious math error either.

Anyone have any tips on where I went wrong?

Comment: `let unit_direction = r_in.direction().normalized();` is what you should have there according to the tutorial.

Comment: Wow.  Just wow.  So I missed adding the normalized method long ago and wrongly assumed that it was a deprecated method or something and just proceeded without it since it never impacted anything.  I've had other typos and things I had to work around from the tutorial and thought that was just another one of them.

Answer (score 2):

So I missed adding the normalized method long ago and wrongly assumed that it was a deprecated method or something and just proceeded without it since it never impacted anything. I've had other typos and things I had to work around from the tutorial and thought that was just another one of them.

Adding that method to the Vec3 type like so:

```
pub fn normalized(self) -> Vec3 {
    self / self.length()
}
```

Solved the issue for me.  Works like a charm now.